# FetchXML vs Query Expression vs LINQ Query: What should I use here?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

I need help from those kind enough to provide help! I am running an instance of Dynamics 365 and I need help deciding whether to use FetchXML, LINQ Query or Query expression to query an entity I have called contract lines....

Let me explain the project:

Inside the contracts entity, I have contract lines that look like this:

[image]

The contract lines (summed together) will tell you what to order (and how much to order) for each day of the week, for the entire duration of the contract. The duration of the contract could be 6+ months.. What I want to do is take this information and expand it. So I want to get what the orders would be like for each day of the contract from start of the contract until the end of the contract. Once a contract is created, a record is created in another entity called Unit Orders, like this:

[image]

Inside the unit order entity, there is a subgrid of another entity (called the alter unit order entity). This entity has a 1:N relationship to the unit order entity. Just like how the data from the contract entity went into the unit order entity, we want the data from the contract line entity to go into the alter unit orders entity. The trick here is writing an algorithm that processes the data from contract lines into the alter unit orders entity. We are summing up how much is being ordered for AM SNACK, LUNCH and PM SNACK for each day of the contract. Please note that the orders are only filled on weekdays (there are no orders for the weekends). I have already started writing the plugin and I have managed to query the contract line sub-grid from the contract entity. My problem is, I am stuck at that and I need help putting together the algorithm to spit out what I want... here is what I have so far:

```c#
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;


/// <summary>
/// This plugin takes the data provided in the contract lines and makes Unit Orders.. Inside the unit orders, an Alter Unit Orders table is present.
/// The Alter Unit Orders table describes the daily order for each day in the contract's duration. 
/// </summary>

namespace DCWIMS.Plugins
{
    [CrmPluginRegistration(MessageNameEnum.Update,
    "contract",
    StageEnum.PreOperation,
    ExecutionModeEnum.Synchronous,
    "title",
    "Post-Update Contract",
    1000,
    IsolationModeEnum.Sandbox,
    Image1Name = "PreImage",
    Image1Type = ImageTypeEnum.PreImage,
    Image1Attributes = "title")]
    public class UnitPlugin : IPlugin
    {



        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            // Extract the tracing service for use in debugging sandboxed plug-ins.
            // Wil be registering this plugin, thus will need to add tracing service related code.

            ITracingService tracing = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            //obtain execution context from service provider.
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            // The InputParameters colletion contains all the data passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                //obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                //verify that the target entity represents the the contract entity and is in an active state
                if (entity.LogicalName != "contract" && entity.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("statecode").Value != 0)
                    return;

                //obtain the organization service for web service calls.

                IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory =
                        (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));

                IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                //Get Contract StartDate
                DateTime startDate = (DateTime)entity["activeon"];

                //Get Contract EndDate
                DateTime endDate = (DateTime)entity["expireson"];

                //Get all weekdays in the contract duration
                Eachday range = new Eachday();
                var weekdays = range.WeekDay(startDate, endDate);       //weekdays list

                //Get Contract Number
                string contractNumber = (string)entity["contractnumber"];


                //Query and aggregate each Weekday's order for the 3 different meal times...

                //AM SNACK


                //LUNCH


                //PM SNACK

                var am_list = new List<int>();
                var lunch_list = new List<int>();
                var pm_list = new List<int>();

                foreach(var day in weekdays)
                {
                    var alterunit = new Entity("new_alterunitorder");
                    alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_orderdate", DateTime.Parse(day));

                    switch (day.Split(',')[0])
                    {
                        case "Monday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[0]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[0]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[0]);
                            break;
                        case "Tuesday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[1]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[1]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[1]);
                            break;
                        case "Wednesday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[2]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[2]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[2]);
                            break;
                        case "Thursday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[3]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[3]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[3]);
                            break;
                        case "Friday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[4]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[4]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[4]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected value ({day.Split(',')})");
                            break;

                    }
                    alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_name", contractNumber);
                    service.Create(alterunit);
                }

                }

                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occured.. Phil is responsible.", ex);
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracing.Trace("An Error Occured: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code I am using to fetch all weekdays for the contract duration:

```c#
public class Eachday
{
    public List<string> WeekDay(DateTime from, DateTime thru)
    {
        List<string> days_list = new List<string>();
        for (var day = from.Date; day.Date <= thru.Date; day = day.AddDays(1))
        {
            days_list.Add(day.ToLongDateString());
            if (day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday || day.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
                days_list.Remove(day.ToShortDateString());
        }

        return days_list;
    }
```

I added this in the try block to get a list of weekdays:

```c#
                //Get Contract StartDate
                DateTime startDate = (DateTime)entity["activeon"];

                //Get Contract EndDate
                DateTime endDate = (DateTime)entity["expireson"];

                //Get all weekdays in the contract duration
                Eachday range = new Eachday();
                var weekdays = range.WeekDay(startDate, endDate);
```

I need to put the weekly order quantities into a list for each day of the week. Essentially, I am going to have 3 lists. Then I would use the lists in a switch to spit out the totals!!

```c#
                foreach(var day in weekdays)
                {
                    var alterunit = new Entity("new_alterunitorder");
                    alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_orderdate", DateTime.Parse(day));

                    switch (day.Split(',')[0])
                    {
                        case "Monday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[0]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[0]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[0]);
                            break;
                        case "Tuesday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[1]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[1]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[1]);
                            break;
                        case "Wednesday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[2]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[2]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[2]);
                            break;
                        case "Thursday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[3]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[3]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[3]);
                            break;
                        case "Friday":
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_amsnack", am_list[4]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_lunch", lunch_list[4]);
                            alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_pmsnack", pm_list[4]);
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine($"An unexpected value ({day.Split(',')})");
                            break;

                    }
                    alterunit.Attributes.Add("new_name", contractNumber);
                    service.Create(alterunit);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are debuting with plugins. I find the `QueryExpression` pretty complicated in general. Instead you should use a `fetchXml`. In short, `fetchXml` is the language for queries in Dynamics. All the views use it. You can generate fetchXml in the advanced find window.

[image]

In term of performance, it's also the best. To my knowledge, there is no other options, in plugins, to calculate a sum without retrieve the whole data in memory.

Here's a example I found in MSDN

```cs
string estimatedvalue_sum = @"  <fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' aggregate='true'> 
    <entity name='opportunity'> 
       <attribute name='estimatedvalue' alias='estimatedvalue_sum' aggregate='sum' /> 
    </entity>  </fetch>";

EntityCollection estimatedvalue_sum_result =
_serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(estimatedvalue_sum));

foreach (var c in estimatedvalue_sum_result.Entities) {
    decimal aggregate7 = ((Money)((AliasedValue)c["estimatedvalue_sum"]).Value).Value;
    System.Console.WriteLine("Sum of estimated value of all opportunities: " + aggregate7);

}
```

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309565.aspx#sum

Also, here's general tips:

- `_serviceProxy` is the service variable
- In the target, you will find what has changed
- In the pre image, you will find what was before your change
- Post images are useful when you trigger different plugins on the same event, and I always recommend to avoid that. Keep everything in the same class, it gives you more control.

**First Revision:**
You could create an entity containing the sum for each day. Replace "(Money)" by the right type. Not sure if it's currency or int.

```
foreach(var unit in unitsum_am_result.Entities)
{
    decimal mondaySum = ((Money)((AliasedValue)unit["new_mondayunits_amsum"]).Value).Value;
    decimal tuesdaySum = ((Money)((AliasedValue)unit["new_tuesdayunits_amsum"]).Value).Value;
    decimal wednesdaySum = ((Money)((AliasedValue)unit["new_unitswednesday_amsum"]).Value).Value;
    decimal thursdaySum = ((Money)  ((AliasedValue)unit["new_unitsthursday_amsum"]).Value).Value;
    decimal fridaySum = ((Money)        ((AliasedValue)unit["new_unitsfriday_amsum"]).Value).Value;

    var unitOrder = new Entity("new_unit_order");
    unitOrder.Attributes.Add("new_orderSum", mondaySum);
    unitOrder.Attributes.Add("new_date", mondayDate);
    _serviceProxy.Create(unitOrder);

    // Do the same for the other sums/days
}
```

**Second revision**
To get a lookup value from the contract, the best option is to create a pre-image, on your plugin, using the plugin registration tool. In the image, select the fields you need to retrieve from the entity. It works like the target.

```
PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages != null && PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages.Count >= 1 ? PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages.FirstOrDefault().Value : null;
```

[image]

Be aware, if on your update event you do not modify the Unit, you will find the value in the image. If you do update the Unit, you will find the old value in the image and the new value in the target. So you always have to check both.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about it? Should I just make 3 lists (one for each meal of the day) and feed the sums into these lists?! Then at the end I would have four lists (including the weekdays list) that I can iterate through to make a record for each day of the contract?! I just have to make sure to repeat for each week until each list becomes as long as the weekday list?!

Comment: It's gonna depend on how you calculate each of your meal in the contract. Will you make a contract line for each day? Will you deduce the number of days required by substracting the contract end date by the start date? You can do multiple fetch to determine what number of each meal you have. There is no problem with that.

Comment: I did what you recommended and changed it above (please check it out).. again I'm confused about what to do with the retrieved Entity collection. The contract line is essentially being expanded to give information about each day's order, so the sum of Monday will be the first day, Tuesday is the next day until the end of the week.. Then it repeats week after week (such information is dumped into another record called alter unit orders)! The purpose of this is that each day's order can then be modified from the alter unit order entity, the contract is just a template!

Comment: Hey nick, I'm testing out the query in Xrmtoolbox and it is summing up data from different contracts.. I need it to return data from a single related contract per execution!! I'm thinking maybe this is handled by the execution context in the plugin??! What are your thoughts?!

Comment: In the filter you forgot to specify the contractid

Comment: How can I give it a contract ID? It could be any one of the contracts depending on which contract invoked the execution of the plugin! So when a contract is made, after its invoiced the plugin goes and fetches the contract lines for that contract only! This would be happening every time a new contract is made..

Comment: The target = the contract. The target is always the entity from which the event is fired. So you can get the id of the contract by doing target.Id.

Comment: Try this filter: <filter type='and' >
  <condition value='100000002' attribute='new_servingtime' operator= 'eq' />
  <condition value='0' attribute='statecode' operator= 'eq' />
  <condition value='" + target.Id.ToString() + "' attribute='contractid' operator= 'eq' />
</filter >

Comment: What do you have in mind? FetchXML should be a string. Try doing the filter in the Advanced Find with an existing contract then download it. May be you'll understand better.

Comment: Ah sorry. I have the habit to always name the variable target. In fact, in the code above it's named entity -> Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

Comment: I did this: <condition value='" + targetId + @"' attribute='contractid' operator='eq' /> </filter>.. I added this to the top before the try block:               var targetId = entity.Id.ToString();   Do you think that's fine?!

Comment: Hey nick, I ran a unit test, I'm getting an exception thrown... for some reason, the lists I'm creating are not returning values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51429719/system-collections-generic-keynotfoundexception-the-given-key-was-not-present-i

Comment: Hey nick, the statement PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages != null && PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages.Count >= 1 ? PluginExecutionContext.PreEntityImages.FirstOrDefault().Value : null; am I adding that to the if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity && ......); ???

Comment: No it is a different object

Comment: I have the unit field locked, it cannot be updated.. The field is set by a workflow that only triggers when a contract is created!

Comment: Add the pre image below the target statement as a standard. Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

Comment: Add my blog to your RSS feed. I will try explain this kind of stuff in next days. xrmmtl.com

Comment: Hey nick, I need to figure out what happens when fetchxml query doesn't return anything... does RetrieveMultiple return null or an empty object?! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486027/what-does-entitycollection-return-if-fetchxml-query-didnt-find-anything

Comment: estimatedvalue_sum_result.Entities.Count == 0

Comment: Nick, the problem is when I enter only one line in the contract lines the plugin won't execute..I tried writing if (unitsum_am_result.Entities.Count == 0) then am_list.Addrange(Enumerable.Repeat(0,5)); so that it would place zeros in the case that no lines exist for one of the meal types.... Unless I have three lines for each of the meal types, the plugin won't execute!

Comment: Look on how to debug a plugin. Also, what are the filtering attributes? On what does the plugin trigger?

Comment: I made you a post with some explaination. Xrmmtl.com

Comment: I debugged the plugin.. It seems that the If(unitsum_lunch_results.Entities.Count == 0) statement is being skipped if there is no data retrieved from the corresponding FetchXML Query. Please take a look at the full debugging, scroll all the way to the bottom: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486027/what-does-entitycollection-return-if-fetchxml-query-didnt-find-anything